# Tensor Product of Graphs and Eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tensor-products

Sorry if langauge is not so clear, I don't know very well the excat translation of terminology to English.

Question:
$G_1,G_2$  are undirected simple/strict graphs.
$A_{G_1}, A_{G_2}$ are adjacency matrixes of the graphs above.
 1. If $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of $A_{G_1}$,and $\beta$ is an eigenvalue of $A_{G_2}$.
then prove that $E * E'$ is an eigenvalue of $A_{G_1 \otimes G_2}$

2. G is undricted simple/strict graph, $\omega(G)$ is the second biggest eigenvalue in it's absolute value for the normalized adjacency matrix of graph G, prove : 
   $\omega(G_1 \otimes G_2) = \max\{\omega(G_1),\omega(G_2)\}$

I'm preety clueless about this subject so you can be extra informative on how to solve it, I'll be grateful.
Thank you!.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Already did, Thank you for enlighting me.